# Is a time series with a constant value stationary

Tags: time-series, stationarity

I would like to know, if a time series with a constant value for every t is a stationary time series or not? So actually this time series has the same variance, expectation value and autocorrelation for every t which would imply that it is stationary. But on the other hand I read several times that a stationary time series does not have any predictable pattern in the long-term (e.g. [Forecasting: Principles and Practice](https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html),[Basic Time Series Analysis](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/487377_18327e7d7e87412282b92d870de14de0.html), [An Introduction to IoT Analytics, Page 118](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/487377_18327e7d7e87412282b92d870de14de0.html,%20https://books.google.de/books?id=1N0mEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&lpg=PA118&dq=stationary%20time%20series%20%22no%20predictable%20patterns%22&source=bl&ots=YaxMTXmL7l&sig=ACfU3U27z-u3RPwqC8wCQ9jKsjbKxbZOJg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdxcqiypj2AhVcQvEDHSsABx4Q6AF6BAgoEAM#v=onepage&q=%22no%20predictable%20%22&f=false)). So I am a little bit confused as a time series with only a constant value definitely has a predictable pattern in the long-term.

Comment: A constant time series has autocorrelation of $\frac00$ (i.e. undefined)

Comment: The exact quotation is "Generally, stationary time series have no predictable patterns in the long run." The qualifier "generally" must be respected as signaling there may be exceptions.  Moreover, this statement is really empty of content, because "predictable patterns" could mean anything.  It is made as a *heuristic:* to help you understand and interpret the more rigorous, quantitative definitions and descriptions.

Comment: Hi: The statement "stationary time series does not have any predictable patter in the long term", IMHO, is worse than empty. It's just  wrong. Any series that is mean reverting and stationary has a predictable pattern in the long term. So, I would disregard that definition for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually you can find this statement "Generally, stationary time series have no predictable patterns in the long run" in many many books and websites. So would you then say that a time series with just a constant value is in fact stationary?

Comment: It is strictly stationary. Not sure about weak stationarity, though, as autocorrelation is undefined (see Henry's comment). Also, a big +1 for mlofton's comment.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks for your comments

Comment: @Richard I would say it's also weakly stationary, because it's better to define the latter in terms of the moments rather than functions of the moments.  Specifically, a constant time series process has constant mean, variance, and covariances (at all lags), whence it is second order weakly stationary.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. I trust your expertise and I find the way you approach this logical.

Comment: @mlofton: What do you mean with "Any series that is mean reverting and stationary". Something like the green curvers with regular cycles here: https://chih-ling-hsu.github.io/2017/03/20/time-series. Because - opposed to the labeling in the figure - this time series is not stationary.

Comment: Hi PeterBe: Your green curves look more cyclic to me. So, for example, take the following series: $y_t = \rho y_{t-1}  + \mu + \epsilon_t$. Suppose $\rho$ is positive and less than one.  Given some large shock, $\epsilon_t$, this series will veer off for a while but, eventually, in the long term it should come back to ( i.e. revert to ) $\mu$. So it is stationary even though it might go off in some direction for some time before it comes back. The amount of  time will depend on the size of the shock and the value of $\rho$.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @mlofton: Thanks for your answer. I don't think that the green curve is cyclic if you take the defintion of https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/cyclicts/. It looks seasonal but for me definitely not cyclic. Further, how do you know that your choosen time series is stationary?

Comment: You could be right about cyclic. To be honest, I'm not sure of the difference between cyclic and seasonal. In my comment, I should have said reverts to $\frac{\mu}{1-\rho}$ because that is the long term mean (not $\mu$). How do I know that the series I chose is stationary ? I know  because the long term mean is constant and equals  $\frac{\mu}{1-\rho}$ and  the long term variance is constant and equals $\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\rho}$. For the derivation, you can look in any decent time series book that covers the AR(1) with a non-zero mean.  ( box jenkins, hyndman, chatfield etc ).

Comment: @mlofton: Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome but check out a time series textbook that has the stationary derivation for an AR(1) with a non-zero mean. For $-1 < \rho < 1$, you'll see how the long term mean and variance are derived and this implies that it's stationary. Abraham and Ledolter is , IMHO, a good introductory time series text which I forgot to mention earlier.

Comment: @mlofton: Hi mlofton, it's me again still having problems understanding the concept of stationarity. Can you say that a cyclic or seasonal or periodic time series is not stationary?

Comment: Hi and no problem: You want constant mean and constant var which is not true with seasonal or cyclic.  But, the concept of stationarity is really only meaningful AFTER you take out the seasonality or the cycle. So, to talk about stationarity in the context of cyclic or seasonal series is not really clear. Note though that, in the arima framework, there is the concept of a seasonal unit root. So, I would check out that what is meant by that in more detail ( I've never dealt with it. Just seen it )  because what I'm saying about taking them out first, might not apply in that case.

Comment: @mlofton: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. So it is correct to say that a seasonal or cyclic time series is not stationary, if I understood correctly, as they don't have a constant mean (but they can have constant variance as far as I see it)

Comment: Hi: I hope someone else can pipe in here because seasonaility and cycles are not in my bag of knowledge. When one talks about stationarity and constant mean and constant variance, they are referring to the LONG TERM UNCONDITIONAL mean and variance. So , I'm pretty sure that a seasonal series can still be viewed as stationary from a long term unconditional mean and variance standpoint as long as the seasonality doesn't change over time.   Like I said, to others reading this, if someone can comment on the issue of stationarity when there is seasonality or cycles, it's appreciated.

Comment: @mlofton: Thanks for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. Okay, let's wait and hope that someone else will give his/her comment on this issue. As far as I undestand seasonal time series can't be stationary because they don't have a constant mean for all time slots as the seasonality effects the mean (by definition). So I am not sure whether it is really correct what you infer. But I am also not an expert on that and can surely be wrong on this one.

Comment: I hope so also. The thing is that the mean is unconditional so it should be the mean over the whole series so one would possibly think that the seasonalities cancel out when the mean is taken. But hopefully someone else can help us here. Thanks for good question.